# ffmpeg add text with fade in effect

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a simple music video with a single image background and the lyrics showing up in a fade in and fade out effect during the video.

Like stuff done with After Effects. Can a quality fade in and fade out be done with ffmpeg?

What would be the command to call when trying to achieve a simple text fading in the middle of the video at about 10s, fading out at 15s and then the next one? etc...

If possible please include a solution with background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ASS subtitles. They are easy to create in [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/). If you **must** have fades use the `/fade` or `/fad` [override tags](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/).

Once you make the subtitles you can run your `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bg.png -i music.m4a -vf "subtitles=lyrics.ass" -c:a copy -vf format=yuv420p -shortest output.mkv
```